What's the meaning of the "the inconsiderate act of existing"?

"Why don’t you leave if you don’t like it,” he said to her one day in
answer to a complaint encompassing the house, his father, his sister,
himself, the entire town; and then her stricken face had filled him
with anguish not only for what he had said but for the inconsiderate
act of existing.

​
it is an excerpt from the novel Fat City by Leonard Gardner.
does this phrase mean "besides what he had said he was also angry obout his anger that dominated him at the moment." ? Or " he was angry about the fact of his existence."?

inconsiderate means to not take the feelings of others into account when one acts or speaks.  Going beyond that basic fact would involve interpretation of the book, and it is a matter of opinion whether he is being sarcastic or not, feeling a sense of deep shame or not, or looking back later upon his emotion and feeling different now than he did at the time. Voting to close for that reason.

@TimR thank you. Yes I know its meaning. But using these words was odd. As you said it seems sarcastic. However if it is sarcastic, why should her face filled him with such anguish? I think the narrator wants to say he is angry with himself because he feels he is useless and at the same time what can he do? He couldn't give birth to himself. Maybe the narrator wants to show his contradictory feelings.

Those are reasonable questions but off-topic for this site.

@TimR excuse me I didn't know that. Is this kind of question against the rule of this forum?

Questions about interpretation of literature are considered off-topic but questions about the literal or figurative meaning of phrases in poems and fiction are allowed, if they are not easily found in a dictionary, or if the definitions in dictionaries are not clear enough.  You are asking about the character's feelings, and so that has strayed into off-topic territory.  You might try literature.stackexchange.com

"He" is anguished (sad, not angry) about the fact that he exists.
The situation can be paraphrased thus:

She made a complaint
He said, in response to her complaint, "Why don’t you leave if you don’t like it"
She looked stricken (sorrowful)
Seeing that he had made her so sad, he felt deeply ashamed

he felt ashamed at having said the thing that made her sad
he felt ashamed that he even exists - because, we can surmise, just his presence seems to cause her to feel bad.  He thinks it would have been better for her if he had never lived.




He was anguished (not angry) that he had been so inconsiderate as to exist, once he saw in her face how much pain he had caused.
The use of "inconsiderate" is tongue-in-cheek, since it's not typically expected that a person would have consider whether to exist or not, or whether their existence causes others pain. His feeling of guilt is so strong that he regards even his existence as something for which he could be considered culpable.

It is odd, because when a person in an argument says 'Pardon me for breathing!', they are generally being sarcastic, and not really sorry for being alive.

@MichaelHarvey Quite so. I had to reread the excerpt to make sure it was intended sincerely, that he wasn't reading this in her face or something.

That means someone has been in much pain and he thinks he is burden.
